# Null Reference Exception when clearing content from flowdocument

Tags: c#, dispose, nullreferenceexception, flowdocument

I am clearing content from FlowDocument using Dispatcher.The code is in non UI assembly. The code is

```
     Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
         new Action(delegate()
    {

    _flowDocument.Blocks.Clear();
    }
```

However I am facing null reference exception whenever this code executes.

---

Well I already have a thread (forgot about it while posting the question) to perform operations on FlowDocument, So I just need to call the above mentioned code using a delegate .

Comment: Have you tried to use _Invoke_ instead of _BeginInvoke_? & Where _flowDocument is set in your code?

Comment: Yes I did but no help. It is class level variable and I am creating its new instance in one of the private methods.

Comment: When you debug, is __flowDocument_ _null_? or _Blocks_?

Comment: Nothing is null... still getting this exception

Comment: In this case, you will have to give us more information about our code.

Comment: One of these is null:   _flowDocument, or Blocks. Check for flowDocument != null first, then flowDocument.Blocks != null.

Comment: @Ram, if any of this is not null - then you have some thread that sets  _flowDocument or Blocks variables to null, and this happens in debugging. Try to find all places where this two variables can be set to null, or perhaps ctors.